# ObservableList ReadOny Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection, readonly

I have created the following extension of the observable list to mimic a readonly behaviour.

```
public class WeirdList<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{

    public new void Add(T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Add function not implemented.");
    }

    public new void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Insert() not implemented.");
    }

}
```

However, if I bind this to a datagrid that has CanUserAddRows=true then when I add a row on the datagrid via the GUI, then no exception is throw yet I can see the object has been added to the collection despite having overridden the obvious methods that allow adding.

If i try to add in code, as expect the exception is thrown.

Any help?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't overriden the functions, just redefined them. You need to use `override` not `new`. The grid probably casts the datasource to an `ICollection` which means your functions wont be called. They will only be used if the object is exactly your type.

As mentioned in the comments `Add` and `Insert` are not virtual, override function `InsertItem` instead. (Add and insert both call this function internally)

Comment: Add isn't declared as virtual:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132404(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Attempted to add override for InsertItem but no effect.

Comment: if you override insert item and add an item (not using the grid) to the collection does it throw the exception?

Comment: Ah hah, i didn't override insert item correctly. It is now working!

Answer (score 0):

You've declared your add method like this:

`public new void Add`

You're **shadowing** the base class's version.  The DataGrid is likely using the base class's `Add` method.

If you're declaring the list that your grid will bing to as

`ObservableCollection<T> Src = new WeirdList...`

Then change it to

`WeirdList<T> Src = new WeirdList...`

Since the `Add` method in `ObservableCollection<T>` is not declared as virtual, and therefore cannot be overridden.

If that doesn't work, then that will mean that the grid is casting your collection, thereby obviating all your hard work, rendering what you want to do impossible.

Comment: I have added other functions to my WeirdCollection with some events which seem get get called fine. I don't understand how the datagrid can be casting as ICollection but my other functions/events still remaining in working condition.

Comment: Are the other methods that you've successfully changed declared as virtual in ObservableCollection<T> ??